# Автодополнение (автозаполнение) строки в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

Нужно реализовать что-то на подобе гугловской строки запроса, когда пишешь несколько начальных символов, а тебе из базы данных подтягиваются имеющиеся совпадения.

На [java](/questions/tagged/java)нашла специальную огромную библиотеку, которую просто присоединила к lineEdit и оно идеально работает.

Не подскажет ли кто нибудь, имеется ли такая библиотека для [qt](/questions/tagged/qt), а если нет, то хотя бы примерный алгоритм для написание кода.

Comment: Да тупо так шлёшь на сервер `"SELECT phrase FROM table WHERE phrase LIKE CONCAT(" + Textbox.Text + ",'%')"` (ну или как там у вас конкатенация выглядит), и выводишь хинтом первые десять или сколько-то там вариантов (впрочем, LIMIT-ить можно прямо в запросе), если юзер ещё не успел чего дополнительного жмакнуть...

Comment: Просто начинать такое дело с первого символа, как то глупо, учитывая нереальные размеры базы. И как реализовать, что б например с третьего символа при каждом последующем выводилось более точное значение и не будет ли это перегружать сервер, если я после ввода каждого символа буду посылать запрос?

Comment: *начинать такое дело с первого символа, как то глупо, учитывая нереальные размеры базы.* Логичечно... но кто мешает тупо смотреть, сколько символов юзер навводил, и пока их не станет хотя бы три, не дёргаться? опять же индекс по этому полю неплохо бы иметь - способствует... если ищем по начальным символам, а не по подстроке. И поиск - асинхронно, чтобы не тормозило.

Comment: В Qt автозаполнением в lineEdit занимается QCompleter: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html#details

Comment: Нашла только реализацию, когда создается список, на основе которого коиплитер потом выбирать совпадения. Это правильно или можно как то "поизящнее" сделать?

Comment: @МашаГрачова, ему можно целую модель скормить из которой он сам будет цеплять... правда насколько это будет эффективно с большой таблицей из БД — я бы проверил...